# Why the names of my structures and templates ends with "- unknown"?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'm using Liferay 6.2 EE sp 11 and I'm developing a theme.

I used the resource-importer to import all the structures and template inside my site ([Resource Importer Guide](http://www.liferay.com/it/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/importing-resources-with-your-themes-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-09-en)).

Now I just want to know why ALL the names of Structures and Template imported through theme end with "- unknown": so if in my theme i called the related file "testStructure.xml" when i deploy the theme the name of the structure will be "testStructure - unknown".

What I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the name of the structure end with the version of Liferay like "testStructure - 6.2.3"

Can you check in your liferay-look-and-feel.xml if version is set. It should look like:

```
<look-and-feel>
    <compatibility>
       <version>6.2.3+</version>
    </compatibility>
</look-and-feel>
```

Comment: Unfortunately i have it. Thanks anyway.